# Need help identifying / converting old video from mobile phone

Tags: file, video, mobile, format

I apologize in advance for the noob question but I need help rescuing some very old videos retrieved from a LG 8380 mobile phone. I don't know the original extension of the file so I don't know what format is it in. I tried changing the extension to .3GP .AVI .MP4 but it does not play in any program (VLC, BS Player etc). When I change the extension to .mjpeg only the first frame is shown then the video stops. I tried converting the .mjpeg to MP4 but I end up with a 1 frame video.

I tried putting the fine in HEX editor to see any info and the first line is LGMJPGE.

When using online file analyzers they think it's a ARCHANGEL archive because of the LG at the beginning of the string, but that's there because the phone was a LG.

Any suggestions?

One video can be found here:

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlDq_HCrQH5Vhu1oHyODN_X3sKTOHw?e=Bz8eot

Comment: The file appears to be in .mjp format and it seems (I can't try) that handbrake (https://handbrake.fr/) can open it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. I changed the extension to .mjp but got the same results from all the programs/converters and handbrake says it's not supported. I also tried playing the file from some LG phones with various extensions and none work. Surely there must be a way of extracting more than one frame from it